# How to proof linearity property of summations with induction

Tags: summation, induction

Recently I have faced with this question:

$ {\sum_{k=1}^{n} (ca_k+ b_k) = c \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k + \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k }$

Proof linearity property of summations for all n ≥ 0 by using mathematical induction on n

I know that proving with induction is basically trying with $P(1)$, $P(m)$ and $P(m+1)$ however in my previous examples, right hand side always had one simple equation with only n variable. This does not, so I don't know how to solve this. Could someone explain and solve please? I progressed until here, don't know what else to do:

$ {c \sum_{k=1} ^{m} a_k + \sum_{k=1} ^{m} b_k + ca_{m+1}+ b_{m+1}} $

Comment: Have you tried anything? You may be surprised how straightforward this ends up being. Your base case will be for n=1, giving you $\sum_{k=1}^1\left(ca_k+b_k\right)=ca_1+b_1=c\sum_{k=1}^1 a_k+\sum_{k=1}^1 b_k$.

Comment: Yes but as I said only n becomes 1, there are other variables($a_k$, $b_k$, $c$ and so on) and I don't really understand what to do next...

Comment: @KennyHegeland, I updated my question and added what point I came up till.

Comment: You are very close. Factor out the $c$ and you have $c\left(\sum_{k=1}^m a_k + a_{m+1}\right) + \sum_{k=1}^m b_k + b_{m+1}$. Now do you see where to go? Hint: how can you rewrite $\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} a_k$ to look like what you have?

Comment: @KennyHegeland

I am way too confused now.

I am not too sure whether my $P(m+1)$ statement is true:

${ \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} (ca_k+ b_k) = c \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} a_k + \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} b_k }$ which would be:
${ \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} (ca_k+ b_k) - \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} b_k = c \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} a_k  }$
but does not make sense to me...

Comment: You are essentially done at the point I left off. We know that $\sum_{k=1}^m b_k + b_{m+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$. Similarly, we have $\sum_{k=1}^m a_k+a_{m+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k$. So above where we factored out the $c$ is essentially the final step when you consider these facts.

Comment: I thought we don't actually apply those rules, therefore splitting them like $\sum_{k=1}^m bk + b_{m+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{m+1}} would be inappropriate(well, that's what I thought), but if that's the way, then I'll do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We can rewrite it like that since we have $$\sum_{k=1}^m b_k + b_{m+1} = b_1+b_2+b_3+\ldots+b_m+b_{m+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k.$$

Answer (score 1):

We proceed as normal with induction (see Guido Kanschat's post for the general process). When $n=1$, we have
$\sum_{k=1}^1 \left(ca_k+b_k\right)=ca_1+b_1=c\sum_{k=1}^1 a_k+\sum_{k=1}^1 b^k$, so our base case holds. Now suppose that for some $k\in\Bbb{N}$ our proposition holds (that is $\sum_{i=1}^k \left(ca_i+b_i\right) = c\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+\sum_{i=1}^k b_i$).

Now we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \left(ca_i+b_i\right) &=& \sum_{i=1}^k \left(ca_i+b_i\right)+(ca_{k+1}+b_{k+1})\\
&=&\left(c\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+ca_{k+1}\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_i+b_{k+1}\right)\\
&=& c\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+a_{k+1}\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_i+b_{k+1}\right)\\
&=&c\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}b_i.
\end{eqnarray}

I skipped a few steps (hence the ellipsis) in this last equation, I hope you take the time to figure out why the equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

The usual induction process applies:

1. Show that this holds for $n=1$.
2. Assume it holds for $n-1$ and show it holds for $n$.

I assume this is a homework question, so it would be unfair to write down the complete answer.

Comment: Thank you, I know that usual process applies, but I am stuck at a place. To be honest this is not a homework, it is a revision material.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the full proof.**

Statement:
$$\text{Let}\space P(n)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^n(ca_k+b_k)=c\sum_{k=1}^na_k+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k:n\in\Bbb{Z}_{\ge0}$$
Inductive step:
$$\text{Two cases: when $n=m$, and when $n=m+1$}$$
$$\text{We know that $P(n)$ is true $\iff P(n)$ is true}$$
$$\therefore\text{$P(m)$ is true $\iff P(m+1)$ is true}$$
$$P(m)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^m(ca_k+b_k)=c\sum_{k=1}^ma_k+\sum_{k=1}^mb_k\iff P(m+1)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(ca_k+b_k)=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
Proof:
$$\text{Assuming $P(m)$ is true,}$$
$$P(m+1)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(ca_k+b_k)=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
$$\equiv\sum_{k=1}^{m}(ca_k+b_k)+(ca_{m+1}+b_{m+1})=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
$$\equiv c\sum_{k=1}^ma_k+\sum_{k=1}^mb_k+c(a_{m+1})+(b_{m+1})=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k\because P(m)\equiv\sum_{k=1}^m(ca_k+b_k)$$
$$\equiv c\sum_{k=1}^ma_k+c(a_{m+1})+\sum_{k=1}^mb_k+(b_{m+1})=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
$$\equiv c\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^ma_k+(a_{m+1})\Biggl]+\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^mb_k+(b_{m+1})\Biggl]=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
$$\equiv c\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k\Biggl]+\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k\Biggl]=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
$$\equiv c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k=c\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}a_k+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}b_k$$
Conclusion:
$$\{\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}\}\Longrightarrow P(m)\equiv P(n)\space\text{is true}$$
$$\therefore\text{Q.E.D}\space P(n)\space\text{is true}$$